# Absolute value integral

Tags: integration

I think this is trivial but my mind does not work as it should. I have the following sequence of functions:

\begin{equation}
f_n(x)=\begin{cases} n(1-n|x+2|), & |x+2|<1/n \\
0, & |x+2|\geq 1/n\end{cases}
\end{equation}
and I want to compute the following integral:

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f_n(x)|dx
\end{equation}
Of course this integral is not improper, since it is defined on the line $(-1/n, 1/n)$ but after that I must decide upon the sign of the value inside the integral and so on. I know that the similar to the above, when $x \to x+2$ is:
\begin{equation}
\int_{-1/n}^{1/n}|f_n(x)|dx=1
\end{equation}
but I need the steps in between in order to understand the procedure for the one above.

Once again excuse, I know it is too simple. Thank you.

Comment: You need to find the sign of $f_n(x)$ ?

Comment: @Augustin I need to find the sign of $f_n(x)$, or else how am I going to be able to compute the integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $f_n(x)=0$ for $-2-\frac{1}{n}<x<-2+\frac{1}{n}$.

Then you have $n(1-n|x+2|)>0$ for $|x+2|<\frac{1}{n}$, i.e.  $-2-\frac{1}{n}<x<-2+\frac{1}{n}$.

Thus 
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f_n(x)|dx = \int_{-2-\frac{1}{n}}^{-2+\frac{1}{n}}n(1-n|x+2|)dx
\end{equation}

Then a little more work is needed to get rid of the absolute values in $|x+2|$.

Comment: Are you sure of the part that $f_n(x)=0$? I think it is the same inequality at the part where $f_n(x)=0$ and $f_n(x)>0$. Also, can you go one step further and tell me how to get rid of the $|x+2|$ inside the integral? Because I think that the limits of integration will change once again.

Comment: Yes it is the same because $-2-\frac{1}{n}<x<-2+\frac{1}{n}$ is equivalent to $|x+2|<\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Then you have to consider the cases $x>-2$, where $|x+2| = x+2$ and $x\leq -2$, where $|x+2| = -x-2$. And you cut your integral into two parts : from $-2-\frac{1}{n}$ to $-2$ and from $-2$ to $-2+\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Ok, I find the result to be equal to: $I=8n^2+n+2$. Is that correct? I know that I ask too much, but for me it is important that I learn to do that in the right way.

Comment: So, I did the math again and now I found it to be equal to 1. So apparently I had to be a bit more careful while evaluating. So, can I make a guess and say that each one of this kind of integrals, defined by these sequences, but only differ at the part where $|x+x_0|$ are equal to 1?

Comment: You're right. Actually if you make the graph of $f_n$ you'll see that this integral is just the area of a rectangle.  As you've said, you can replace the $2$ by any $x_0$, it changes nothing (with a change of variables you can always take $x_0=0$).